# Ruby String Arrays Overwriting Themselves?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, overwrite

For some reason, string is getting rewritten as mirror by the operation mirror[j] = string[i]

I have no idea why this would be, I'm not commanding it to. The outputs of my reverse(string) function will stop at the middle, like:
ABCDEF -> FEDDEF
but I'm trying to do:
ABCDEF -> FEDCBA

```
def reverse(string)
  mirror = string
  i = string.length - 1
  j = 0
  while j < string.length
    mirror[j] = string[i]
    puts(mirror)
    j = j + 1
    i = i - 1
  end
  return mirror
end
```

Comment: cannot you just use ruby string api for this? like str1.reverse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-dup). In your case, `mirror = string` means both the variables are holding the reference of the same object. So, when you change the object, that can be reflected through both `string` and `mirror`.

```
def reverse(string)
  mirror = string.dup
  i = string.length - 1
  j = 0
  while j < string.length
    mirror[j] = string[i]
    j += 1  # same as j = j + 1
    i -= 1  # same as i = i - 1
  end
  mirror 
  # last expression is returned by default, so you can write only  `mirror` instead of `return mirror`
end

p reverse 'ABCDEF' # "FEDCBA"
```

Comment: I'd upvote, but I can't because I don't yet have 15 reputation points! Thank you!

Comment: another option is not duplicating the string at all, but append-concatenating `<<` chars to the mirror